# Vue components in vue-markdown

Tags: vue-component, markdown

I'm attempting to use [VueMarkdown](https://miaolz123.github.io/vue-markdown/), using a `postrender` function to add some custom things like so:

template:

```
<vue-markdown :source="post.body" :postrender="postRender"></vue-markdown>
```

script:

```
function postRender(input: any){
  return = input.replace(/(\>|\s)@([a-z0-9-]+)/g,"$1<user :val='$2'></user>");
}
```

The `postrender` input is an html string and expects a return of an html string to be used in the DOM.  `<user/>` being a component means it is not compiled, so the output ends up being like:

```
example <user :val='@user'></user> test
```

I've looked into a number of options like trying to compile the string before returning, wrapping the `vue-markdown` in a dynamic component, etc.  At this point, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong and probably need to start from the beginning with this.  So, how can I use a custom component in a markdown element in Vue?